# How does sscanf() see numbers in a string?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem with sscanf() in the following code:

```
void num_check(const char*ps){
char *ps1=NULL;
int number=0;
unsigned sum_num=0;
ps1=ps;

for(;*ps1!='\0';ps1++){
    if (isdigit(*ps1)){
      sscanf(ps1,"%d",&number);
      sum_num+=number;
    }
    }
printf("Sum of digits is: %d",sum_num);


}


int main(){

printf("Enter a string:\n");
char str[20];
gets(str);
num_check(str);
return 0;
}
```

The problem is: when I input a string in the form of "w2b4e" it sums my numbers OK, and I get the desired result. But when I try to input a string such as "w23b4e", what it does is: it sees the number 23 in the loop, so variable `number=23`, and s`um_num=23`, but the next step in the loop is this: `number=3`, and `sum_num=26`. And in the next step `sum_num= 30`...
This confuses me quite a bit. Since I don't believe that sscanf() has such a quirky flaw, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result do you expect from `w23b4e`? 27 or 9?

Comment: by the way, It is enough to  use  *ps1! and omitting !='\0' since '\0' expresses 0

Comment: @woryzower thx, I use it probably because I still haven't mastered C as well as I would like... :D

Comment: @woryzower: Some code conventions (notably, Google's internal one) recommend always comparing variable with same type constant instead of bool casting. Similarly, you'd comapre pointer to NULL, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum digits (not the whole number), use the following instead:

```
if( isdigit(*ps1)) {
  sum_num += *ps1 - '0';
}
```

You can also use `sscanf("%1d", ps1)` to make it read only one character.

Comment: @R Burny thx, that was it. I entered "%1d", and that was it. Btw, why *ps1 - '0'? What does that do?

Comment: ASCII characters are represented in memory as consecutive integers (although '0' digit is mapped to integer 48, not 0). So `'0' = 48, '1' = 49, ..., '9' = 57`. Hence `*ps1 - '0'` calculates what digit you have. For example, `'7' - '0' = 55 - 48 = 7`. Writing '0' lets you not rely on magical constant 48.

Answer (score 5):

You always advance by exactly one character in the loop: `ps1++`. You probably want to advance `ps1` to the first digit instead.

Better yet, there's a function called `strtol`. It tries to parse integers from strings and can return the position of the first character that could not be read. So you can use `strtol` in a loop to sum everything that looks like a number in your string.

---

If you want to sum digits instead of numbers found in a string, it's easier:

```
while (*p) {
    if (isdigit(*p))
        sum_num += *p - '0';
}
```

Comment: @cnicutarno, it's ok to advance only one character, the problem is that if I have one digit after another it pairs them as a number eg. "23", and in the next step it sees the second part of the number eg. "3".

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;*ps1!='\0';ps1++){
if (isdigit(*ps1)){
  sscanf(ps1,"%d",&number);
  sum_num+=number;
}
}
```

you are incrementing ps1 one character at a time, independently of how many digits are being read. Unfortunately you cannot use sscanf for this task, since you are not able to know how many characters have been read.

Answer (score 0):

sscanf works like it should, it doesn't move beginning of pointer, you are moving it by one character in for loop.